# Not redirecting properly in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have an old asp.net webform based website for which i want to redirect traffic from HTTP to HTTPS

i am using below code

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://example.com") || HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://www.example.com"))
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.RedirectPermanent("https://www.example.com/en/", false);
}
```

Above code should work for all url that are HTTP based but it only redirect properly below url only

Redirect works for below

- http://example.com is redirected to https://www.example.com/en/
- http://www.example.com is redirected to https://www.example.com/en/

but if i have longer url as below it doesn't redirect

- http://example.com/en/news/news-title1
- http://example.com/en/news/news-title2
- http://example.com/en/blog/blog-titlex

I am not sure if am doing something wrong in code? as i am using `.Contains()` it should redirect all url which are HTTP based to HTTPS

**Update**: i realized i have to use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` to get the full URL path.
Even after changing the code `if` block doesn't get executed and i noticed two things

- that output for `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` return Secure but on browser it always show non secure as show in screenshot
- secondly when i run same page on Incognito or as Private on Chrome or FF it redirects from shows page as secure but doesnt execute the if statement.

So in both cases things are confusing

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://example.com") || HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://www.example.com"))
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.RedirectPermanent("https://www.example.com/en/", false);
}
```

[image]

test.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try debugging to see if this code is actually hit for those URLs? Where have you put this code?

Answer (score 1):

its because you check for the name and not for the secure `http` vs `https` Here is an other example that's check for secure connection only, not for the url.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;

        if(!app.Response.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            app.Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl.Replace("http://","https://"), true);
            return;
        }
    }
```

### update

The lock with the red line across means that is partially encrypted - means that some links inside your page is still http.

With the code above you can make sure that all links that pass from asp.net will me secure - if still continues to show that partial secure, check the javascript links (or other links) that all are secure.

Comment: Definitely will try your code as it should work. it seems my code doesn't check for http part. as i understood `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()` also gets the http part also. i  can replace it with `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` to get the complete URL just made a mistake in code which i didnt notice

Comment: @Learning this `Request.RawUrl` is the complete url  - the `IsSecureConnection` can check for the http/https

Comment: @Learning - the lock there means partial encrypt, I have update my answer

Comment: Page i am testing is just a simple test page with no links i doubled checked just to be sure. its simple asp.net webform page with no link in .aspx file and asps.cs just has the code as mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Learning check for plugins, check with other browser